# How to scrape latitude longitude from java script

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, pandas-groupby

I am fairly new to BeautifulSoup4 and am having trouble extracting latitude and longitude values out of javascript. The file is quite long and I have to prepare data frame from all the latitude longitudes

The Java script file will have strings like these:

```
var marker_9795626cfd584471ab4406d756a00baf = L.marker([19.041691972000024, 72.85052482000003],{}).addTo(feature_group_ad623471194f451d9f1cf7fc718747c5);
```

The marker id, here, would be - 9795626cfd584471ab4406d756a00baf
The latitude would be - 19.041691972000024
And the longitude would be - 72.85052482000003

How to extract marker id, latitude and longitude out of the strings using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Javasascript script, so BeautifulSoup won't execute/parse it. You can use `re` module to get the information.

For example:

import re

```
txt = '''var marker_9795626cfd584471ab4406d756a00baf = L.marker([19.041691972000024, 72.85052482000003],{}).addTo(feature_group_ad623471194f451d9f1cf7fc718747c5);'''

marker_id, lat, lon = re.search(r'marker_([a-f\d]+).*?\[(.*?), (.*?)\]', txt).groups()

print(marker_id)
print(lat)
print(lon)
```

Prints:

```
9795626cfd584471ab4406d756a00baf
19.041691972000024
72.85052482000003
```

---

EDIT: To parse the variables from file, you can use this script:

```
import re

with open('<YOUR FILE>', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        m = re.search(r'marker_([a-f\d]+).*?\[(.*?), (.*?)\]', line)
        if m:
            marker_id, lat, lon = m.groups()
            print(marker_id, lat, lon)
```

---

EDIT2: New version:

```
import re

with open('<YOUR FILE>', 'r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

for marker_id, lat, lon in re.findall(r'marker_([a-fA-F\d]+).*?\[(.*?),\s*(.*?)\]', data):
    print(marker_id, lat, lon)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, how can  I use it for the whole file instead of just txt variable? The file is quite long and there are many co-ordinates to extract in same format. How to extract all of them using 're' module?

Comment: Hey there, the above result is not printing the marker ids and co-ordinates. The piece of code work for the first entry though. Is there any way to convert it into data-frame each time an entry is extracted and hence printing all into a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

if *all* you need is to isolate those 2 numbers from that string try this:

```py
def parse(text):
   return [float(i) for i in text.split('[', 1)[1].split(']', 1)[0].split(', ')]

long_lat = parse(your_string_var)
```

EDIT:
oh and to get the id something like this should do:

```py
def parse2(text):
   return text.split('_', 1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0]

id = parse2(your_string_var)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, how can I use it for the whole file instead of just first entry? The file is quite long and there are many co-ordinates to extract in same format. How to extract all of them using this method?

Comment: what you can try is to split the text in the file by lines, then isolate the lines that you are interested in(e.g. lines you are interested in start with `"var marker_"`, or something like that, get creative), then feed those lines into the `parse` and `parse2` functions to get your result